# In cassandra, is there some way to know which node will be chosen when CL=ONE

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to cassandra.
I build a cluster with 10 nodes and want to test CL=ONE.
Here is my understanding after reading documents.

For example, when CL=ONE, a read request comes to the coordinator node,
if this node doesn't have the data, it will forward the request to one of the nodes who holds it by snitch.
Well snitch should decide which node will be chosen by some conditions(such as network latency, etc).
Now I just want to know is there some way to see this particular node (hostname or ip, etc)?

Additionally, if I disabled "dynamic snitch", then how cassandra will decide which node should be chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a misunderstanding. Consistency Level does **not** define how many nodes will be reached to retrieve (or store) data. Whatever your CL is, all responsible replica nodes will be reached in parallel, for example, if you have RF=3 for a keyspace, three nodes will be always contacted. Then, depending on the scenario:

- For Writes, the query coordinator will wait for the specified by CL amount of acknowledgments ("I'm a replica node, I confirm I got your data"). If you set CL=1, it will wait for the fastest answer.
- For Reads, it will ask all replicas for the data and give you an answer as soon as it gets enough **matching** answers.

Snitches do not define which node will be contacted, they participate in token-aware network topology.

P.S. I strongly recommend taking a free [Cassandra course](https://academy.datastax.com/#/curricula/eca8a762-0181-48a8-b1b5-f98e01376bc3) on DataStax Academy, it may save you from many issues in production.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Actually I have been through that course, but too many details didn't show even in current documents. Maybe I got misunderstanding for some parts. But I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Snitch define the “topology” of cluster, all snitches also use a dynamic snitch layer that monitors read latency and, when possible, routes requests away from poorly-performing nodes.

To see the nodes used by query enable the query tracing "**TRACING ON;**"
Ref: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html

To see the nodes that own the partition data, the **getendpoints** that provides the IP addresses or names of replicas that own the partition key.

**nodetool getendpoints** <keyspacename> <tabname> <partitionkey>

Ref: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsGetEndPoints.html

Comment: Thanks, "getendpoints" will list all nodes that hold the data. But I want to know which node will respond the particular request when CL=ONE.

Comment: use  "TRACING ON;" for trace the query

Comment: Thanks, I have enabled trace. But from the logs, still I can't tell which one node will be chosen. Looks that Hades is right, cassandra doesn't care which node will be chosen. May it's just a random pick when multiple endpoints can meet the current CL.

Comment: I can see which nodes are alive, which nodes are not in trace log, BTW. If alive nodes are multiple, won't show which node responds.

Answer (score 1):

For reads, the coordinator will read from CL stated replicas. (Speculative retries can increase the number of replicas read from.)

Most drivers today are token-aware, meaning single-partition requests will always go to a coordinator that has a replica for that partition.

For example, if you read with CL.ONE only the replica on the coordinator will be read.

Server side speculative retry (the table option `speculative_retry`) will result in additional replica reads, if the initial replica reads take too long (according to the configured value for speculative retry).

If Speculative retry is configured to ALWAYS then all replicas are immediately read.

When CL >1 or token-awareness is not applied, replicas are chosen by gossip status (isAlive?), proximity, latency (if dynamic snitch is enabled), and finally their natural ordering.

The code for this can be read in [StorageProxy fetchRows(…)](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/067f4c74612698881feec09039d71d12a5936418/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/StorageProxy.java#L2019-L2085) and [AbstractReadExecutor. getReadExecutor(…)](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/067f4c74612698881feec09039d71d12a5936418/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/reads/AbstractReadExecutor.java#L184-L209) and [ReplicaPlans.contactForRead(…)](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/067f4c74612698881feec09039d71d12a5936418/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/locator/ReplicaPlans.java#L544-L560) and [ReplicaLayout.forTokenReadLiveSorted(…)](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/067f4c74612698881feec09039d71d12a5936418/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/locator/ReplicaLayout.java#L328-L334).